# GStreamer splitmuxsink `Queued GOP time is negative` error

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

We're hitting this error when running a GStreamer pipeline to capture HLS video segments:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSplitMuxSink:splitmuxsink: Timestamping error on input streams
Additional debug info:
../gst/multifile/gstsplitmuxsink.c(2594): handle_gathered_gop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSplitMuxSink:splitmuxsink:
Queued GOP time is negative -0:00:00.035816292
Execution ended after 0:22:00.008870101
```

The pipeline that produced this error is

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://$USER:$PASSWORD@$IP is-live=true protocols=tcp \
    ! rtph264depay wait-for-keyframe=true request-keyframe=true \
    ! h264parse \
    ! splitmuxsink name=splitmuxsink max-size-time=10000000000 send-keyframe-requests=true muxer=mpegtsmux location=segment%05d.mp4
```

There should not be any errors when running the pipeline. I tried setting `config-interval=-1` on the `h264parse` node, but the issue persists.

Comment: This seems to be a bug when splitmuxsink is used in a pipeline with data coming from rtspsrc. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/2703. There doesn't seem to be a solution for it yet, but maybe you could use a different element such as the one suggested (mux fmp4).